# Passing date as parameter for query in visual basics

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to pass a date as parameter in vb to query the data from the table.
If I hardcore the value in the query it works fine for me, but if I pass it as parameter to query, like I am getting the data from edit text and trying to send that as a parameter, this does not work.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM VehicleAnalogParamDownload2
 WHERE Vapd2_Date between 'From_date.Text' And 'To_Date.Text'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't embed the values directly in your SQL statement.**

Use a parameterized query instead. That way you don't need to worry about different date/time formats, and for other parameters you can avoid SQL injection attacks. Your SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM VehicleAnalogParamDownload2
WHERE Vapd2_Date between @FromDate And @ToDate
```

and you'd then fill in the `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` parameter values programmatically.

See the documentation for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

Comment: thanku jon skeet, i got answer and the same prob can be solved in the this way also "SELECT *  WHERE Vapd2_Date between '" & From_date.Text & "' And '" & To_Date.Text & "'"

Comment: @Datta: That's *not* how you should do it though. That leaves you open to SQL injection attacks, formatting problems etc. **Don't do it.**

Comment: oh okay jon thanku... i am new to this , so i am trying all this trial and error method , thanku once again jon.

Answer (score 0):

in vb

```
dim str as string

str="SELECT * FROM VehicleAnalogParamDownload2 WHERE Vapd2_Date between" & 
     From_date.Text & "' And  '"& 'To_Date.Text'"
```

Comment: That invites a SQL injection attack. Code and data should be separated.

Comment: @vikky: Well, that would be a start, and *might* be enough... but then you'd need to worry about different date formats as well. It's the wrong approach though: separate the code from the data by using a parameterized query.

Comment: ok thanks, keep this thing in mind for later work, thanks again

Comment: @vikky: Good plan :) If you search for "sql injection" you'll find a *lot* of information :)